# how to create scala class similar to java bean but with simple logic to modify the input

Tags: java, spring, scala

I have the following java bean

```
public class ReportTest {

    private Integer Impressions;

    public Integer getImpressions() {
        return Impressions;
    }

    public void setImpressions(String impressions) {
        Impressions = Integer.parseInt(impressions.replace(",",""));
    }
}
```

And tried to use scala class to create a similar one using the following, but it complains syntax error.  Looks like I can't modify _. My purpose is to use scala as spring bean per for following project:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala

```
class Report {

  var Impressions:String = _.replace(",","")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Report(impression: String)  { def getImpression() : Int = Integer.parseInt(impression.replace(",", "")) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java class is weird: the getter and setter for `impressions` do not use the same data type. There's no way you can munge it all together in one Scala `var`, which has only one type.

You can translate your Java class into the equivalent Scala code like this:

```
class ReportTest {
  var _impressions: Int = _

  def impressions: Int = _impressions

  def impressions_=(v: String): Unit =
    _impressions = Integer.parseInt(v.replace(",", ""))
}
```

but it's still very weird because of the different types for the getter and setter.

It seems to me that it should be the caller's responsibility to convert the string into an `Int`. Then, your class can be written trivially as:

```
class ReportTest {
  var impressions: Int = _
}
```